# Flutter, Overflow, SingleChildScrollView. It's a form inside a screen and SingleChildScollView Fix working for me this time?

Tags: forms, flutter, overflow, singlechildscrollview

I've built a few flutter apps while learning to code and have fixed the "overflow" problem with SingleChildScrollView in the past. This issue is different and I can't find a fix here or elsewhere.

I believe the issue is due to having a 'form' within a 'screen'.

The screen 'golf_cart_reg_new.dart' has the appBar and the submit or cancel buttons.

The 'golf_cart_reg_new_form.dart' has the TextFormFields and validation. The overflow error appears to be in the form not the screen. I've tried SingleChildScrollView in everyplace I could think of without any changes.

I'm also sure my code is bloated but again I am learning as I go.

I will post code for both screens below. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: screen_shot]

**---- THIS IS THE SCREEN CODE BELOW ----**

```
import 'package:WelakaOne/logic/golf_cart_new_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/appbar/app_bar_title.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/drawer/end_drawer.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/logic/custom_colors.dart';

import 'golf_cart_reg_home.dart';

class GolfCartNewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GolfCartNewScreenState createState() => _GolfCartNewScreenState();
}

class _GolfCartNewScreenState extends State<GolfCartNewScreen> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.WelakaOneBlack,
        title: AppBarTitle(),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new MyDrawer(),
      endDrawer: new MyEndDrawer(),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              CustomColors.WelakaOneBlack,
              CustomColors.WelakaOneBlueDark,
            ],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: FractionalOffset(1.6, 1.0),
            stops: [0.3, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    'GOLF CART',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.WelakaOneYellow,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    'NEW REGISTRATION',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.WelakaOneYellow,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                  child: GolfCartNewForm(),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              new MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => new GolfCartHomeScreen(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'CANCEL',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: CustomColors.WelakaOneBlueDark,
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: CustomColors.WelakaOneWhite,
                            fixedSize: const Size(220, 40),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**---- THIS IS THE FORM BELOW ----**

```
import 'package:WelakaOne/logic/golf_cart_new_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/appbar/app_bar_title.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/drawer/end_drawer.dart';
import 'package:WelakaOne/logic/custom_colors.dart';

import 'golf_cart_reg_home.dart';

class GolfCartNewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GolfCartNewScreenState createState() => _GolfCartNewScreenState();
}

class _GolfCartNewScreenState extends State<GolfCartNewScreen> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.WelakaOneBlack,
        title: AppBarTitle(),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new MyDrawer(),
      endDrawer: new MyEndDrawer(),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              CustomColors.WelakaOneBlack,
              CustomColors.WelakaOneBlueDark,
            ],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: FractionalOffset(1.6, 1.0),
            stops: [0.3, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    'GOLF CART',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.WelakaOneYellow,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    'NEW REGISTRATION',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.WelakaOneYellow,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                  child: GolfCartNewForm(),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              new MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => new GolfCartHomeScreen(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'CANCEL',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: CustomColors.WelakaOneBlueDark,
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: CustomColors.WelakaOneWhite,
                            fixedSize: const Size(220, 40),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you inserted the same code twice. Please ensure you update the code you shared from `form`.

I had similar issue, and here is the sequence to fix the issue:

`Flexible` **-->** `SingleChildScrollView` **-->** `Form` **-->** `Column`

```
Flexible(
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
         key: _formKey, 
         child: Column(
            children:[Container(
               alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, 
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10, top: 20, bottom: 20), 
                  child: Text("xxx")
```

Let me know if this does not help.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thank you so much :)   I tried scrollview everywhere I could think of, with my limited knowledge, but not on the actual form call. Such an obvious solution and it never occured to me!!! You're best.